# Calling SFTP process from VBA code 

Tags: windows, vba, vb6, windows-xp, sftp

problem - Store key in cache Question  stop VBA app

I use pscp.exe in order to transfer files from windows to Linux machine.

Remark: pscp.exe exists in my VBA code (that client is part of the PuTTY tools)

When I copy files from my PC to any new Linux machines I get the question "Store key in cache? (y/n)" and this interrupts my VBA application (VBA application stopped on sftp process).

I need advice how to ignore the question "Store key in cache? (y/n)". Or maybe automatically sending a "y" key from my VBA code? Or other solution as defined in the PC registry before running the pscp.exe? But how to do that?

Example from WIN XP command line (cmd)

Remark: 192.9.200.120 (Linux server IP address)

> "D:\documents and settings\udavid\pscp.exe"  -sftp -l root -pw pass123
>   "D:\Documents and Settings\udavid\Desktop\scan_ip.ksh" 192.9.200.120:/var/tmp

CMD output :

```
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 1024 15:e1:ce:4f:8e:4e:7b:61:14:c3:df:3c:b1:50:67:b6
If you trust this host, enter "y" to add the key to
PuTTY's cache and carry on connecting.
If you want to carry on connecting just once, without
adding the key to the cache, enter "n".
If you do not trust this host, press Return to abandon the
connection.
Store key in cache? (y/n)
```

Example of CMD output if I use -batch flag (pscp.exe -batch)

```
The server's host key is not cached in the registry. You
have no guarantee that the server is the computer you
think it is.
The server's rsa2 key fingerprint is:
ssh-rsa 2048 d5:80:49:7f:69:f1:29:7c:1f:99:ec:c9:f4:b2:6f:a0
Connection abandoned.
Lost connection

                  ---  Example from my VBA code ---
Const cstrSftp As String = """D:\documents and settings\udavid\pscp.exe"""
Dim strCommand As String
Dim pUser As String
Dim pPass As String
Dim pHost As String
Dim pFile As String
Dim pRemotePath As String
pUser = "root"
pPass = "pass123"
pHost = "xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx - any server new IP
pFile = """D:\Documents and Settings\udavid\Desktop\scan_ip.ksh"""
pRemotePath = "/var/tmp"

strCommand = cstrSftp & " -sftp -l " & pUser & " -pw " & pPass & " " & pFile & " " & pHost & ":" & pRemotePath

Debug.Print strCommand
Shell strCommand, 1
```

Comment: Have you tried using keys instead of passwords? There are several Howto pages from [this google search](http://www.google.com/search?q=ssh%20key%20putty).

Comment: no I must to use the passwords

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Shell "cmd /c echo y | " & strCommand, 1` as a suggested quick hack.

I use a home-made [cExec](http://dl.unicontsoft.com/upload/cExec.zip) class to pipe output and to selectively respond to putty warnings like this

```
With New cExec
    .Run "d:\downloads\pscp.exe", sParams, True
    Do While Not .AtEndOfOutput
        If InStr(.ReadLineOutput, "(y/n)") Then
            .WriteInput "y"
        End If
    Loop
End With
```

Comment: so how to set all params in sParams ? (-sftp -l " & pUser & " -pw " & pPass & " " & pFile & " " & pHost & ":" & pRemotePath" )

Comment: not clearly if I need to install the cExec class? please advice , or just add your code in my VB code ?

Comment: Did you try the "cmd /c echo y | pscp.exe ..." first?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
 echo y|"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\pscp.exe"  -sftp -l root -pw pass123 C:\scan_ip.ksh $server:/var/tmp
```

It will "press" y to your program standar input.

Comment: This will of course also "press" y to the "WARNING somebody is doing something evil" message you'd see during a MITM attack too.

Comment: @rkosegi its not work "echo y" , need to think on other solution

Comment: The `echo` part also means it need to be parsed by the command processor and not the usual `Shell()`

Comment: yes echo doesn’t help in this case , so whats else we can do in order to bring fast solution ? , or  no solution ? please help this is very urgent for me ,

Answer (score 0):

The help (`pscp /?`) gives you the answer.
You should pass `-batch` to disable all prompts like that.

You may also want to quote your parameters correctly so spaces and quotes in the values don't break things.

Comment: is it possible to automated the pscp.exe command with yes answer in the VBA code ?